# Changing request units provision from collection to database in CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way of changing the request unit configuration of a CosmosDB from collection to database without having to recreate the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Once you created a database with Database level RUs or a collection with collection level RUs you cannot change it without recreating the database itself.

Comment: Having hit this issue myself - a follow up: the simplest way to recreate the container is to use Azure Data Factory to copy the data from the affected container to a new container, then delete the original container. Side effect is that you can't reuse the container name (without doing _another_ copy)